# Append link URL based on domain name

Tags: javascript

I want to append any link URLs on a page that has example.com in it.

The following script works, but it only works if the link doesn't have any parameters.

```
<script>
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('example.com', 'example.com?utm_day=monday);
</script>
```

What I need to do is find ANY link on the page with example.com and append it, regardless of the other parameters in the link. For example, the script could find

`<a href="https://example.com?formID=1234">` and append it to be

`<a href="https://example.com?formID=1234&utm_day=monday">`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select all the `a` tags first, then replace them if they include **example.com**.

```
let text = '&utm_day=monday'

document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(
        item => {
            if (item.href.includes("example.com")) {
                item.href += text
            }
        }
    )
```

Comment: WHOA! That is way more elegant and simple than the method I was thinking. You're a wizard!

Comment: Accepted! Can't upvote yet because I don't have enough reputation points. :-P